# Twitter Bootstrap 3: How to reduce action of table-striped and table-hover to certain columns in table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to reduce the effects of the twitter bootstrap classes `table-striped` and `table-hover` to columns 2 and 3. Is there a way to do this? Here is an example of how my table looks like now:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td class="warning">val1</td><td>val2</td><td>val3</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="warning">val1</td><td>val2</td><td>val3</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="warning">val1</td><td>val2</td><td>val3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Moreover I want do add a vertical border between column 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to redeclare some bootstrap `table` classes.

---

Here is a Demo for adjusting background colors. Please change the values to your specific needs:

[**`Custom Table Cell Hover`**](http://jsfiddle.net/jZa7K/)

---

Here is a Demo for adding a border between column 1 and 2 and after the last row:

[**`Custom Table Borders`**](http://jsfiddle.net/dLwhx/1/)

This is how it works:

```
.table-striped td:first-child {
    border-right: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```